# How many connected components in this random graph?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, matching-theory

I was reading [this](https://mathstodon.xyz/@11011110/107140270923344318) blog post about minimum-weight matchings on two-color point sets in the unit square and it got me thinking.

Suppose you have 3 colors (Red, Blue, Green), and randomly drop $N$ points of each color into the unit square.  You then draw the minimum-weight matchings for each pair of colors.  How many components do you expect the resulting graph to have? What is the average size of a component?  Can you say anything else about the distribution of sizes/number of components (aside from the fact that all component sizes are divisible by 3)?

Geometrically: Can two components intersect? Can a component self-intersect? If the answer to both of these questions is No, what can we say about the areas of the regions surrounded by a component?

Addendum: The answer to the latter two questions is Yes, components can intersect and self-intersect. Is there a useful notion of area of a component? What is the expected number of intersections/self-intersections?

Comment: https://twitter.com/thienan496/status/1446021847292669953

Comment: Sorry -- fixed the blog post link.  The post contains a link to that twitter thread as well as some supplementary information.

Comment: Some of these questions can be answered by just trying it out. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaLBi.png) is the result of one trial with $N=100$ points of each color, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8rKz.png) is a representation of the connected components we got, if we forget about the locations of the points.

Comment: Thank you Misha, for doing this -- I didn't have time to program up an experiment myself.  So we see that components can intersect and can self-intersect.  We also see that at least for small $N$ (and $N=100$ counts as small) you can get some very large components.  How does this change as $N$ gets large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm going to post some experimental results here, if no one else is going to chime in.  This is based off of code I've uploaded [here](https://github.com/CHelfgott/Math-StackExch-misc/blob/master/3color-min-matchings.py) if anyone is interested.

Experimentally (after running a number of tests with $N$ between 100 and 1000), you find that 25-30% of the points wind up in cycles of length 3, with another 8-12% in cycles of length 6, and 5% in cycles of length 9.  The average cycle size in this range is somewhere around 9, but there is some indication that it increases with $N$ (and likewise the proportion of points in 3-cycles decreases with $N$). It's a little too early to say for certain though.

The number of intersections and component self-intersections, unsurprisingly, seems to scale with $N^2$, although I can't say much more than that.